# Unable to see Search Box (EditText) when using ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to implement Custom ListView (i.e. ListView with custom Adapter) with Search Box, for that I have written the following XML code--

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CustomListViewAndroidExample" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtInputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search item.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My MenuListActivity code is---**

```
 public class MenuListActivity extends Activity
    {
        ListView list;
        TextView txtInputSearch;
        MenuListAdapter adapter;
        public  MenuListActivity CustomListView = null;
        public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_list);

            CustomListView = this;


            setListData();

            Resources res =getResources();
            txtInputSearch=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInputSearch);
            list= ( ListView )findViewById( R.id.list );  // List defined in XML ( See Below )


            adapter=new MenuListAdapter( CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res );
            list.setAdapter( adapter );        

            txtInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
            {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text = txtInputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }   


    public void setListData()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) 
        {

            final ListModel objListModel = new ListModel();


            objListModel.setMenu("Company "+i);
            objListModel.setPrice("com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/rihanna");
              // sched.setUrl("http:\\www."+i+".com");

            CustomListViewValuesArr.add(objListModel);
        }

    }


    public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
    {
        ListModel tempValues = ( ListModel ) CustomListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition);

       // SHOW ALERT                  

        Toast.makeText(CustomListView,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

***See my Adapter class Below--***

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private ArrayList<ListModel> arrayList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;
    ListModel tempValues=null;
    int i=0;

    public MenuListAdapter(Activity paramActivity, ArrayList paramDataList, Resources paramResource) 
    {
        activity = paramActivity;
        data=paramDataList;
        res = paramResource;
        arrayList=new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        arrayList.addAll(data);

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount()
    {

        if(data.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {         
        public TextView item_name;
        public TextView item_price;       
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_row, null);             
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.item_price=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
           // holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {
            holder.item_name.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );


             holder.item_name.setText( tempValues.getMenu() );
             holder.item_price.setText( tempValues.getPrice());
             /* holder.image.setImageResource(
                          res.getIdentifier(
                          "com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage()
                          ,null,null));*/                           

             vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));
        }
        return vi;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked=====");
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener
    {           
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position)
        {
             mPosition = position;
        }

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {


          MenuListActivity sct = (MenuListActivity)activity;   

            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }               
    }  

 // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText)
    {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        data.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) 
        {
            data.addAll(arrayList);
        } 
        else 
        {           
            for (ListModel lm : arrayList)
            {
                if (lm.getMenu().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                {
                    data.add(lm);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In ***design mode***, when I clicks on ***Graphical Layout*** It is showing me proper/expected view (i.e. Search box to the Top and ListView Below to the search Box) but when I run my application then it is showing only ListView and SearchBox (EditText) is invisible. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change listview layout height to  `android:layout_height="0dp"` instead of         `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CustomListViewAndroidExample" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtInputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search item.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** Use `RelativeLayout` instead of  `LinearLayout`  as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/txtInputSearch" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:completionThreshold="1" 
            android:singleLine="true"/> 

        <ListView  
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtInputSearch"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

Use `EditText` in your code  instead of `TextView` ,So change

```
TextView txtInputSearch;
```

to

```
EditText txtInputSearch;
```

And

```
txtInputSearch=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInputSearch);
```

to

```
txtInputSearch=(EditText )findViewById(R.id.txtInputSearch);
```

Comment: @namo 
then remove android:layout_weight="1" from this layout and add  android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of         android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: @Namo checked edited answer,and reply if it work or not.

Comment: @Namo Try Relative layout instead.See edited answer.

Comment: @Namo did you use relative layout,and i edit it also.

Comment: Yes even I copied your xml.

Comment: @namo what happened in first method,just use my first xml with linearlayout and clean your project before launching your project

Comment: @Namo Or first delete bin  and gen folder from project and launch your project,and reply.

Comment: No.. Still not working..! Please See my edited question In that I have added some other code...

Comment: @namo see my edits and use my first layout in your code,it will work.

Comment: @Namo did you try launching after cleaning your project/or delete bin and gen folders?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, even I removed/uninstalled apk from my mobile and re-installed fresh apk. but still not working... I think there is small silly mistake that we are getting failed to find it out..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a weight into you ListView which would take all the space of your layout, instead dont put any weight on it just simply wrap its height and remove the `android:layout_weight="1"`

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CustomListViewAndroidExample" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtInputSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search item.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**problem:**

```
txtInputSearch=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtInputSearch);
```

You are casting it to a `TextView` not an `EditText`.

**change it to this:**

```
EditText txtInputSearch;

txtInputSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInputSearch);
```

Comment: Algonquin I have removed android:layout_weight="1" but still not working.

Comment: @Namo you copied my xml above?

Comment: Yes I copied your xml.

Comment: which code..? I mean Adapter class Or MenuList Activity..?

Comment: @Namo in your main activity where you initialized you listview and edittext

Comment: Plz see my edited Question, I have given code for both 1] MenuListActivity 2] My Custom Adapter class

Comment: @Namo remove everything in oncreate just setcontentview will be remain and update me what you see.

Comment: I removed everything except setcontentview from Oncreate() but Still getting same result.. It showing only List Items. Search Box is still invisible..